# Why my selection sort code doesn't work?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have this function for selection sort:

```
public static void selectionSort(int[] n)
{
    for(int start = 0; start < n.length; start++)
    {
        int smallest = start;

        for(int i = start+1; i<n.length; i++)
            {if(n[i]<n[start])
                smallest = i;}

        int tmp = n[start];
        n[start] = n[smallest];
        n[smallest] = tmp;
    }
}
```

and i call it like this.

```
Random ran = new Random();
    int n = 10;
    int[] a = new int[n];

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        a[i] = ran.nextInt(1000);
```

However, it causes results like this..

640 900 610 168 650 610 527 356 802 486

486 640 356 168 610 527 610 650 802 900

the top one is not sorted the lower one is supposed to be sorted. However, it is not correct.

Comment: Rather than ask us, why not run it through a debugger?  Or, horror of horrors, step through it on paper?

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing the initial `start` index every singe iteration, even if you have found a smaller number you are still comparing it to the original `start` which should not happen. Once you find a smaller number you need to use that index for the comparison.

To compare it to the smallest number every iteration change `(n[i]<n[start])` to `(n[i]<n[smallest])` and that will fix your problem.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The second loop is useless because you are comparing, after all, just the first and the last item and `smallest` takes it's value from this comparison only.
By your code I guess you're trying to do a [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), but the comparison and the index management is wrong, here is a posible solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random ran = new Random();
    int n = 10;
    int[] array = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array[i] = ran.nextInt(1000);
    }

    printArray(array);
    selectionSort(array);
    printArray(array);
}

private static void printArray(int[] array) {
    System.out.print("Array: ");
    for (int i : array) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

private static void selectionSort(int[] array) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        // Subtract 1 so you don't get a NullPointerException
        // Subtract j so you don't compare the numbers already ordered
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1 - j; i++) {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                int tmp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The algorithm is taken from the [Spanish version](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_de_burbuja) (I'm from Argentina) of the link above, which is also in the English version with other notation.

Hope this helps. Best regards

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this version of code it's functional:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random ran = new Random();
    int n = 10;
    int[] a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = ran.nextInt(1000);
    selectionSort(a);
    for (int i : a) {
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
}

public static void selectionSort(int[] n)
{
    for(int start = 0; start < n.length-1; start++)
    {
        int smallest = start;

        for(int i = start+1; i<n.length; i++)
        {if(n[i]<n[smallest])
            smallest = i;}

        int tmp = n[start];
        n[start] = n[smallest];
        n[smallest] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should refrain from just dumping code and try and give an explanation when you answer someones question.